# Tailwind css footer position not to the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer, tailwind-css

I am new to the tailwind css. I was making my new webpage where I am putting a footer. But the problem is the footer position is relative to the content. That is, if the content is less than the page size, it goes up. I tried googling the problem and found some solutions and none of them worked.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen">    
<!-- navbar -->
<div class="w-full text-gray-700 bg-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 dark-mode:bg-gray-800">
        <div x-data="{ open: false }" class="flex flex-col max-w-screen-xl px-4 mx-auto   md:items-center md:justify-between md:flex-row md:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="p-4 flex flex-row items-center justify-between">
            <a href="#" class="text-lg font-semibold tracking-widest text-gray-900 uppercase rounded-lg dark-mode:text-white focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">Sachchidanand Prasad</a>
            <button class="md:hidden rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @click="open = !open">
                <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="w-6 h-6">
                <path x-show="!open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM9 15a1 1 0 011-1h6a1 1 0 110 2h-6a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                <path x-show="open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
                
        <nav :class="{'flex': open, 'hidden': !open}" class="flex-col flex-grow pb-4 md:pb-0 hidden md:flex md:justify-end md:flex-row">
            <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-gray-700 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="index.html">Home</a>
            
            <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="research.html">Research</a>

            <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-gray-200 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="cv.html">CV</a>  
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- footer -->
<footer class="border-t border-gray-200">
    <div class=" container flex flex-col flex-wrap px-4 py-16 mx-auto md:items-center lg:items-start md:flex-row md:flex-nowrap">
                
        <div class="justify-between w-full mt-4 text-center lg:flex">
            <div class="w-full px-4 lg:w-1/3 md:w-1/2">
                <h2 class="mb-2 font-bold tracking-widest text-gray-900">
                    Useful Links
                </h2>
                <ul class="mb-8 space-y-2 text-sm list-none">
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/" target="_blank">MathSciNet</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes" target="_blank">AMS open Math Notes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="https://mtts.org.in/" target="_blank">MTTS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="https://www.atmschools.org/" target="_blank">ATM School</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="w-full px-4 lg:w-1/3 md:w-1/2">
                <h2 class="mb-2 font-bold tracking-widest text-gray-900">
                    Useful Links
                </h2>
                <ul class="mb-8 space-y-2 text-sm list-none">
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="http://www.nbhm.dae.gov.in/" target="_blank">NBHM</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800">Blogs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="w-full px-4 lg:w-1/3 md:w-1/2">
                <h2 class="mb-2 font-bold tracking-widest text-gray-900">
                    Social Networks
                </h2>
                <ul class="mb-8 space-y-2 text-sm list-none">
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="">Facebook</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="">Twitter</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="">Instagram</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="">Github</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <p class="text-base text-gray-400">
            All rights reserved by @ <a class="text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-800" href="index.html">Sachchidanand</a> 2022
        </p>
    </div>
</footer>
</div>
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: If your content doesn't go more than the screen height, or you don't mind seeing your footer when you scroll down the page, you make the footer fixed to the bottom of the page. Add `fixed bottom-0` to your footer class and your footer should stick to the bottom.

Comment: @Amir_R84 thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want a fixed footer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a `mt-auto` to the footer. See Full Page:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen">    
<!-- navbar -->
<div class="w-full text-gray-700 bg-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 dark-mode:bg-gray-800">
        <div x-data="{ open: false }" class="flex flex-col max-w-screen-xl px-4 mx-auto   md:items-center md:justify-between md:flex-row md:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="p-4 flex flex-row items-center justify-between">
            <a href="#" class="text-lg font-semibold tracking-widest text-gray-900 uppercase rounded-lg dark-mode:text-white focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">Sachchidanand Prasad</a>
            <button class="md:hidden rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @click="open = !open">
                <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="w-6 h-6">
                <path x-show="!open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM9 15a1 1 0 011-1h6a1 1 0 110 2h-6a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                <path x-show="open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
                
        <nav :class="{'flex': open, 'hidden': !open}" class="flex-col flex-grow pb-4 md:pb-0 hidden md:flex md:justify-end md:flex-row">
            <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-gray-700 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="index.html">Home</a>
            
            <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="research.html">Research</a>

            <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-gray-200 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="cv.html">CV</a>  
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- footer -->
<footer class="mt-auto border-t border-gray-200">
    <div class=" container flex flex-col flex-wrap px-4 py-16 mx-auto md:items-center lg:items-start md:flex-row md:flex-nowrap">
                
        <div class="justify-between w-full mt-4 text-center lg:flex">
            <div class="w-full px-4 lg:w-1/3 md:w-1/2">
                <h2 class="mb-2 font-bold tracking-widest text-gray-900">
                    Useful Links
                </h2>
                <ul class="mb-8 space-y-2 text-sm list-none">
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/" target="_blank">MathSciNet</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes" target="_blank">AMS open Math Notes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="https://mtts.org.in/" target="_blank">MTTS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="https://www.atmschools.org/" target="_blank">ATM School</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="w-full px-4 lg:w-1/3 md:w-1/2">
                <h2 class="mb-2 font-bold tracking-widest text-gray-900">
                    Useful Links
                </h2>
                <ul class="mb-8 space-y-2 text-sm list-none">
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="http://www.nbhm.dae.gov.in/" target="_blank">NBHM</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800">Blogs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="w-full px-4 lg:w-1/3 md:w-1/2">
                <h2 class="mb-2 font-bold tracking-widest text-gray-900">
                    Social Networks
                </h2>
                <ul class="mb-8 space-y-2 text-sm list-none">
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="">Facebook</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="">Twitter</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="">Instagram</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800" href="">Github</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <p class="text-base text-gray-400">
            All rights reserved by @ <a class="text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-800" href="index.html">Sachchidanand</a> 2022
        </p>
    </div>
</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using 'h-screen' to set it to the full height of the screen